# Create a Pop-up with labels TextBoxes and buttons in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create a pop up which shows up after you click a button (Add Doctor). which is going to have details of the doctor. First Name, Last name, age, etc. In WebForms

something like this:
 [image: Image1]

sadly I dont have any code because I dont know where to start with this. I am not understanding how to create it just with asp.net and C#.

Most videos I've seen or posts use Ajax or javascript to make this..

any suggestion?

Comment: MVC, Web Forms, etc.?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. web forms

Comment: Try using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174716/2654498 It uses the AjaxToolKit's [ModalPopup](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx). I don't think you're going to get around that, or something else client side.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to creating something like this is with ajax or javascript.
I would suggest investigating BootStrap modals.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Project menu at the top of VS, the first option is "Add Windows Form...". Select this, and then create your UI in the designer as you would normally.  To pass the user entered info back to the main form, you'll need to create a delegate on the second form like:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string name, string email, string password, string address);
```

You'll need to call an event on the second form, when the user clicks OK or something, that matches that delegate format like:

```
this.VisibleChanged(sender, e, this.txtName.Text, this.txtEmail.Text, this.txtPassword.Text, this.txtAddress.TExt);
```

Then, on your main form, to receive that information, you'll need to define the event you call on the second form:

```
private void ChildForm_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, string name, string email, string password, string address)
    {
        //your code here
    }
```

Also on the parent form, you'll need to do something like:

```
private Form2 childForm;
```