# How to make oracle like list of vales (lov) in asp.net (web forms)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, oracleforms

I want oracle forms like list of values (LOV) in asp.net web forms.
How can I build it. 
Any idea or example ?

Comment: Oracle Forms seems to use a popup to display the list of values - you could try something like [ASP.NET WebForms Modal Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174452/asp-net-webforms-modal-popup-window) and add a DataGrid etc

Answer (score -1):

Asp.net web form or mvc it's like baby when you compare it
with oracle adf or oracle form we have to build LOV manually
no efficient component like LOVS in asp.net and gridview
it's simple UI not a complex adf table with high feature
especially control query run time processing asp.net gridview
could hang application server if you not build your paging manually
many problem with Microsoft product especially  web form
and in the MVC no control we need to build everything manually
but there's a good news asp.net dynamic controller can build views by wizard
don't be happy the UI look like anything but not a UI